# Gtk.ProgressBar not working in Python

Tags: python, progress-bar, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to use a progress bar in **Python** and **Gtk3**, but it doesn't get updated. I have read [this](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/progressbar.html) documentation and some questions in this forum (mostly for pygtk) and I really don't get it!

I made a code for testing purposes only. When you click a button, it reads the contents of a directory recursively. My intention is to use a progress bar while reading all these files.

This is the whole code:

```
import os
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    """Progress Bar"""

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Progress Bar')
        self.set_default_size(300, 75)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_border_width(10)

        # read dir contents
        mydir = 'Documents'
        home_path = os.environ.get('HOME')
        dir_path = os.path.join(home_path, mydir)
        self.dir_files_list(dir_path)

        # create a grid
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid(column_homogeneous=True, row_homogeneous=True,
                             column_spacing=10, row_spacing=10)
        self.add(self.grid)

        # create a progress bar
        self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.grid.add(self.progressbar)

        # create a button
        self.button = Gtk.Button(stock=Gtk.STOCK_APPLY)
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_pressed)
        self.grid.attach(self.button, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    # function to read the dir contents
    def dir_files_list(self, dir_path):
        self.dir_list = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
            for fn in files:
                f = os.path.join(root, fn)
                self.dir_list.append(f)

    # function to update the progressbar
    def on_button_pressed(self, widget):
        self.progressbar.set_fraction(0.0)
        frac = 1.0 / len(self.dir_list)
        for f in self.dir_list:
            new_val = self.progressbar.get_fraction() + frac
            print new_val, f
            self.progressbar.set_fraction(new_val)
        return True

def main():
    """Show the window"""
    win = MyWindow()
    win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help from a more experienced programmer is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are processing the whole directory when you are creating the window.  That is even before you show it (in the line with `self.dir_files_list(dir_path)`).  It seems to me you want to call it after pressing the button apply.

There are at least 2 possible solutions: use threads or use iterators.  For your specific use case, I think iterator would be enough, besides than simpler and more pythonic.  I would recommend threads only when you *really* need them.

Instead of walking through the whole directory beforehand and the process them later, you can process each file in each directory at a time.

In your example, I would change the method `dir_files_list` (renamed to `walk`) and `on_button_pressed` as:

```py
from gc import collect
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
```

We now need to import also GObject to use `idle_add` which calls a callback whenever there are no higher priority events pending.  Also, once the task is finished, we need to remove the callback to not call it anymore (we need `source_remove` for that).

I renamed your method `dir_files_list` as `walk` because it seems semantically closer to an iterator.  When we walk through each directory and file, we will temporarily "return" (using `yield`).  Remember, `yield True` means that there are pending items to process. `yield False` means we stop the iteration.

So, the method would be:

```py
def walk(self, dir_path):
    self.dir_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        i = 0.0
        self.set_title(os.path.dirname(root))

        for fn in files:
            i = i + 1.0
            f = os.path.join(root, fn)
            self.dir_list.append(f)

            self.progressbar.set_fraction(i / len(files))

            collect()
            yield True

       yield True

    GObject.source_remove(self.id)
    yield False
```

Now, we update the `progressbar` here.  In this particular part, I am updating the progress bar inside each directory.  That is, it will be restarted in every sub-directory and the progress bar will restart in each of them.  To have an idea of which directory is visiting, set the window title with the current directory.  The important part to understand here is `yield`.  You can adapt this to whatever you want to do.

Once we have walked the whole directory, we have to return `yield False`, but before that we remove the callback (`GObject.source_remove(self.id)`).

I consider here that `self.dir_list` is not useful here anymore, but you might have something different in mind.

You might wonder When and how `walk` is called?  That can be set when the button is pressed:

```
def on_button_pressed(self, button, *args):
    homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    rootdir = os.path.join(homedir, 'Documents')

    self.task = self.walk(rootdir)
    self.id = GObject.idle_add(self.task.next)
```

`self.task` is an iterator, which has the method `next()` that retrieves the next item from `self.task`, which is going to be called whenever there are no pending events (with `idle_add`).  We get the `id` in order to remove the callback once we are done.

You have to remove the line `self.dir_files_list(dir_path)` from the `__init__` method.

One more thing: I called the garbage collector manually (`gc.collect()`) because it could be useful when processing a large directory (depending on what you are doing with them).

Comment: Thanks a lot @gpoo for your help! I'm going to take some time to read this and try to understand and assimilate everything :-)

Comment: Feel free to ask anything that might look obscure or need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First, the problem is that the above code runs too fast, so you see the progress bar update so quick that it seems its not getting updated. It does that because you're not searching the directory and displaying the result at the same time. When the class `__init__` you do the search, and just then when you click the button the list is read and displayed in the progress bar at full speed. I'm pretty sure that if the directory is huge, when you start the script it will take a few seconds for the window to display, and the progress bar will eventually progress in a matter of milliseconds anyway.

Basically the problem you're having is that you're doing everything in the same thread. Gtk is in it's own thread, listening to events from the GUI and updating the GUI. Most of the time, you will be using Gtk.ProgressBar for something that will require some time to complete, and you need to execute both, the GUI thread and the working thread (the one that is doing something), and send updates from the working thread to the GUI thread so it updates the progress bar. If, like the code above, you run everything in the same thread you will end up having this kind of problems, for example when the GUI freezes, that is, it become unresponsive because suddenly the GUI thread is doing some work not GUI-related.

In PyGTK, you had the method `gobject.idle_add(function, parameters)` so you can communicate from the working thread to the GUI thread, so when the GUI thread is idle it will execute that function with those parameters, for example, to update the Gtk.ProgressBar.

My approach to that problem is implemented here, please note is for PyGTK: https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/nested/blob/master/src/lib/nested/core/gallery/loading.py

Basically, it is a "LoadingWindow" that the whole application share. When you want to start loading something or perform some heavy work you had to subclass the WorkingThread class ([example](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/nested/blob/master/src/lib/nested/core/gallery/gallery.py#L98)). Then, you just had to call the `show()` method with a WorkingThread subclass instance as parameter and done. In the WorkingThread subclass, you had to implement the `payload()` function, that is, the function that does the heavy work. You could directly call from the WorkingThread the `pulse` method in the LoadingWindow to update the ProgressBar and should not care about Thread communication because that logic is implemented there.

Hope the explanation helps.

EDIT:

I just ported the above to PyGObject, you can find the example here: https://gist.github.com/carlos-jenkins/5358445

Comment: Thanks very much. With your explanation now I'm able to understand a little bit more about Gtk+ and threads, but I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to implement this in my program... well, at least I'm going to try... I appreciate your effort for explaining what is hidden beyond my problem.

Comment: I updated the answer, check the PyGObject version: https://gist.github.com/carlos-jenkins/5358445

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I'm going to take a look at that version. Gracias!

Comment: I'm giving up, it is too complicated for my skills. I need something simpler, and in one file if possible :) Anyway, thanks a lot!